# What does '*reply.celery.pidbox' stand for

Tags: celery

We are using Celery with RabbitMQ as Broker and Redis as Backend.  We are running into a problem where we see growth in the number of queues inside RabbitMQ with the format:
`000d7a5b-f554-3817-bff4-1397407ae08a.reply.celery.pidbox`

We are not able to understand why these queues are getting created, and why they are not going down.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This Github issue gives some idea: https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/294. I have seen the same issue on our Redis boxes. A comment on the issue recommends disabling gossip and mingle to overcome this.

Hope this is a bit helpful.